# In a nested Python dictionary, why is it that the deepest key need not be instantiated explicitly?

Tags: python, dictionary

The data structure looks like this (not ordered as dictionaries usually are):

> {'b': {'2': 0.02}, 'a': {'1': 0.01}}

When creating such a dictionary, in Python, it's incorrect to not check if 'b' exists, before referencing d["b"]. It's not incorrect though to add the key '2' to the dictionary keyed by 'b', using d["b"]["2"] = float(0.02).

Below is the piece of code that explains this situation. Ignoring the two commented lines, the code splits a line of text and constructs a nested dictionary; in other words, a dictionary of a dictionary.

The two commented lines work if d is a simple dictionary (no nesting). It's not necessary to check if 'a' and 'b' exists.

What would be the explanation?

```
def f():
  d = {}
  m  = ["a 1 0.01", "b 2 0.02"]

  #d["a"] = 1
  #d["b"] = 2

  for i in range(2):
    (m0,m1,m2) = m[i].split()
    if m0 not in d:
       d[m0] = {}
    d[m0][m1] = float(m2)
```

Comment: Could you give an example line of code that causes the issue?

Comment: You can use `d=defaultdict(dict)` if you want `d[x][y]=z` to create the inner dict when necessary.

Comment: Half a dozen times in 6 minutes!

Comment: this question makes little sense

Comment: Do you mean it does not fail if not instanciated first? Or just that it must be instancianted first before assigning a value to it?
The first would not be the normal python behaviour, the second would. And yes, you can define d as a collection.defaultdict(dict) so that you don't have to test if the key exists already, if not, it'll add it for you, if yes, it'll just assign the value to it.

Comment: Your question is not clear.  Are you asking for an explanation of why something *does* work, or why something *doesn't* work?  Also, it would simplify matters if you just use literal dicts in your example.  Using code that creates dicts by parsing strings just complicates matters.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The difference is that

```
d["b"] = 2
```

represents the call `d.__setitem__("b", 2)`, while

```
print d["b"]
```

represents

```
d.__getitem__("b")
```

If "b" is not already a key in the `dict`, then the first simply adds the key, while the second raises a `KeyError`.

Your line,

```
d["b"]["2"] = float(0.02)
```

is evaluated from left to right, though. It is parsed the same as

```
(d["b"])["2"] = float(0.02)
```

which means `d.__getitem__("b")` must succeed before its result can call `__setitem__`. It is equivalent to

```
d.__getitem__("b").__setitem__("2", float(0.02))
```

---

As an aside, if Python supported true "multidimensional" dictionaries, then something like `d["b"]["2"] = float(0.02)` would map to something like `d.__setitem__("b", "2", float(0.02))`, and most uses of `defaultdict` would become unnecessary.

Comment: Thank you. I wanted to know this detail. (I appreciate your patience, SO can be an unnerving place.)

Comment: Where could I have found this in Python documentation?

Comment: Information about `__getitem__` and `__setitem__` are in https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html; otherwise, you just need to recognize that the `[]` "operators" must be applied one at a time, so that `d["b"]` resolves first before `["2"]` can be applied to the result.

Comment: Right, it was evident that d["b"]["2"] wouldn't ever work since d={} says nothing about it being a dict-of-dict. I tried d={{}} ;-), it wouldn't talk! So eventually it lead me to want to know what the implementation was, and where to look for this detail.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question right, the reason is that `d['b']['2']` is composed of two operations: one does `d['b']` and the other does `...['2']`, where `...` is the result of `d['b']`.  There is no notion of a "nested dict" per se; you just have to access the dicts one by one from the outside in.

In an operation like `d['b']['2'] = 'blah'`, only the last operation (the `...['2'] = 'blah'`) is a setting operation.  The other is a read operation, just reading the value of `d['b']`.  This operation, as you note, fails if `d['b']` does not exist.

In other words, `d['b']['2'] = 'blah'` is the same as:

```
x = d['b']
x['2'] = 'blah'
```

You seem to be aware that the first operation will fail if `d['b']` does not exist.  That is also why it fails for `d['b']['2'] = 'blah'`.

Answer (score -1):

```
def f():
  d = {}
  m  = ["a 1 0.01", "b 2 0.02"]
  for i in range(2):
    (m0,m1,m2) = m[i].split()
    if m0 not in d:
       d[m0] = {}
    d[m0][m1] = float(m2)
  print d
  print type(d)
  print type(m)
  print (d['a']['1'])
  print type (d['a']['1'])
  print (d['a'])
  print (d['b'])
f()
```

gives the output:
    {'a': {'1': 0.01}, 'b': {'2': 0.02}}
    type 'dict'
    type 'list'
    0.01
    type 'float'
    {'1': 0.01}
    {'2': 0.02}

This is hopefully a little more expository than the example you gave:  but I think the simple answer for the question you're asking is:

you're trying to re-assign an integer value, not a dictionary key